# is it almost a standard that web applications assume the query string to be in UTF-8?

Tags: webserver, url-encoding

when we type in or paste it to a browser's address bar:

http://www.google.com/search?q=%E5%A4%A9

i think there is no way to tell whether the encoding is UTF-8 or any other encoding, so the application will usually assume it is UTF-8.  So is it entirely up to the app to interpret it as whatever encoding it wants to or assumes to be?

(for all websites and even the platform i worked on, they seems to be almost always UTF-8)

**Update:** changed to the webapp instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) says:

> "When a new URI scheme defines a
> component that represents textual data
> consisting of characters from the
> Universal Character Set [UCS], the
> data should first be encoded as octets
> according to the UTF-8 character
> encoding [STD63]; "

So UTF-8 is definitely the way to go for any new HTTP GET apis.

Answer (score 0):

The servers don't care. They just pass it to PHP or Ruby or whatever.

Comment: "Server" can also refer to the whole computer, not just Apache/IIS/etc.